# Finding device using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I have an LG Lucid (Andriod 4.0.4) via Verizon and trying to get my app to run on it. I'm using WinXP Pro. The version of ADB is Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31. On the phone I have the USB debugging option turned on and just installed and rebooted both the PC and the.

`C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached`

`C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools>`

Comment: Have you installed Lucid's device drivers? This page might help you: [how to set up LG Lucid for Android App Development](http://lge-phones.org/how-to-set-up-lg-lucid-for-android-app-development.html)

Comment: You must have appropriate drivers installed for the ADB to see your device. What drivers have you installed? Have you tried installing drivers from `\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`?

Comment: Did you download the LG Lucid driver?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: its a dumb question, but did you flashed a custom rom? sometimes adb isnt working - maybe a bug in the custom rom? ;)

Answer (score 2):

In nexus devices I select ptp instead of mtp USB connection and adb see my device

Comment: I had the LG driver installed, but I went to LG site and found a newer version. Had to uninstall the older and now I see it. Under the device manager I actually see 
ADB Interface -> LGE Andriod for VZW ADB Interface

@ the command line I now get:

C:\>adb devices
List of devices attached
4ad6b00 device